# How to child-proof my home for a toddler?

Tags: toddler, safety

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What home-safety aspects should new parents consider?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/2528/what-home-safety-aspects-should-new-parents-consider)

I am aware of the following sources of information. Is there anything else I should do to prevent accidents?

- http://www.babycenter.com/0_childproofing-around-the-house_460.bc
- [How do you childproof electrical cords?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/2808/how-do-you-childproof-electrical-cords)
- [What can I do to baby-proof my home entertainment system?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/2924/what-can-i-do-to-baby-proof-my-home-entertainment-system)

Comment: This question is very similar to "What home-safety aspects should new parents consider?" which is a SE community wiki. You will find great suggestions under that question. Since this question is so similar it may need to be closed as a duplication.